# T4 template generating library with new name

Tags: t4

I have a .tt file that has been working for a while. Recently, when I make changes, it has begun building an output file with a 1 at the end of the file name.  At first, this caused problems because, having output.cs and output1.cs, I had duplicates of all my classes.  However, when I delete them both, running the custom tool creates the ...1 file.  If I then change it, and run it again, I still get the ...1 file (with the changes).  How do I get back to having the original file name without the suffix?

I am running VS 2017.  I have tried stopping and starting the IDE, and I found my .suo file and deleted it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the csproj file and fix the `LastGenOutput` setting that is associated with the your tt file:

```
<None Include="GeneratedCode\YourTemplate.tt">
    <LastGenOutput>YourFile.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```